# smartctl: Confusing attributes and selftest results

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart

The server where I keep old photos, videos and the like contains a bunch of spinning 3TB disks (WD Caviar Green). I rarely switch it on.

I recently looked at my disks' SMART data. One of the disks seems to have two flaky sectors that are waiting for being remapped (full output of `smartctl -a` below). However, I can read these sectors.

**My questions**: According to the smartctl man page, VALUE <= THRESH indicates *end-of-product life from old-age or normal aging and wearout* for Old_age attributes. However, all Old_age attributes feature a THRESH of 0. How should I interpret this? Will this disk never age?

Also, reading the selftest's *LBA_of_first_error* doesn't seem to result in an error, and doesn't increase the *Raw_Read_Error_Rate*. The *LifeTime* corresponds to the *Power_On_Hours* attribute, i.e. the tests reported here are recent. What's going on here?

My real question is whether I should get rid of this disk.

Full test results:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.10.0-20-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Green
Device Model:     WDC WD30EZRX-00D8PB0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4NDRX3STA
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2602ac529
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Feb  1 01:40:44 2023 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (40860) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 410) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       140
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   175   167   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6225
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       691
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       49
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1384
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       691
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   188   188   000    Old_age   Always       -       38288
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   126   113   000    Old_age   Always       -       24
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1383         1304826960
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      1381         1304826960

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
user@debian:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null bs=512 count=20 skip=1304826950
20+0 records in
20+0 records out
10240 bytes (10 kB, 10 KiB) copied, 0.75492 s, 13.6 kB/s
user@debian:~$ sudo smartctl -A /dev/sdb | grep Read_Error
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       140
```

Comment: "*reading the selftest's LBA_of_first_error doesn't seem to result in an error,*" -- Perhaps the selftest error caused a remap of the bad block, so that now that LBA is okay? There are also seek errors in the log. Did this HDD experience shock? I've seen much older drives (20K POH) with better looking stats (zero errors of any kind).

Comment: Thanks sawdust. I interpret *Current_Pending_Sector* as the number of sectors that require remapping, and can't be remapped because they can't be read. Regarding the drive itself, it lives in a very quiet environment with its peers (who have a clean SMART record), but they are all Green drives, which probably means less than stellar reliability.

Comment: The SMART attributes show no error - the value `200` means normalized "no error". Remark: It seems to me that your `dd` has skipped one block too much. Try `skip=1304826959`.

Comment: Use a recent version of smartmoontools and post the full logfile. Do you really expect a reasonable answer based on only the few attributes that you show?

Comment: Why do you cut put parts of report?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ran another SMART report with a new version of smartmontools and included it in full. I also modified the dd command, which now reads an area surrounding the supposedly unreadable sector rather than only the offending sector. Neither the number of pending sectors nor the number of read errors changes, and I continue to have the same questions.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the smartctl man page, VALUE <= THRESH indicates
> end-of-product life from old-age or normal aging and wearout for
> Old_age attributes. However, all Old_age attributes feature a THRESH
> of 0. How should I interpret this? Will this disk never age?

Of course it will age. However the manufacturer didn't set any hard boundary. Even if it did, such values are no 'guarantee' the drive will fail once these are reached. I agree with r2d3, it's a judgement call.

If you'd ask me, none of the attributes look alarming. Not even the 2 pending sectors if this value has remained steady for some time, but this is purely based on personal experience limited to a few drives only with one or 2 reallocated sectors (they continued functioning without issue for many more years). To address those you need to write to them. A full read/write surface scan would:

- Take care of the pending sectors
- Allow you / the drive to discover issues with other sectors

You can use the extended SMART test or tools like HD Sentinel or Western Digital's diagnostic tool.

You can also use these tools to examine and adjust power management to reduce future load cycles.

Comment: I should indeed perform the full scan that you recommend, and I will probably repurpose this disk for less critical data. Right now it is used as part of my backup solution.

Answer (score 0):

The decision to get rid of the disk or not depends of your risk tolerance.

1384h or 5 days of assumed continuous use is a pretty low figure, compared to disks that were running over years with no pending sectors. That means that you are faced with unreadable sectors in an early stage of life of your disk.

Assuming that the data on your disk is somehow valuable the following applies:
If you don't do backups you would need to get rid of this disk now.
From my experience the pending sector count (or rather the reallocated sector count) either stays at that low one-digit figure for years or it increases at an increasing rate now.
If you want to keep the drive you will have to monitor that figure to avoid suffering from data loss once the raw value of this attribute is on the rise.

You should not consider a decrease of this value as a good thing. The pending sectors do net get repaired. They get remapped to healthy sectors once the disk receives a write command to overwrite their content.

Unfortunately the equivalent attribute
"reallocated sector count" is not visible here.
Instead you have "reallocated event count" which does not necessarily reflekt the numbers of sectors being remapped (one event could cover remapping of a couple of sectors) so that you could not simply look at the sum of the currently pending sectors and the remapped ones (as a measure of total sector dammage) because you are delivered the remapping events instead of the number of sectors.

The other attributes did not ring my alarm bell except for the high load cycle count (38288) which is high in relation to the time the drive was running (1384h).

Modifying the original power saving settings could increase the life expectance of your drive at the expense of power consumption.

For more information about this problem read
https://idle3-tools.sourceforge.net/

Please ignore any statements about looking at normalized values on the internet. As there is no common standard about how to normalize, normalized figures are manufacturer-specific which is the opposite of "normalized".

Comment: What you are telling me is the kind of advice I was seeking. Since this disk **is** my backup, I guess I should not use it for that purpose anymore. It has been a member of a RAID-5 array so far, but I am in the process of reorganizing the data (mostly family videos and photos; is there anything more valuable? Luckily most of that is replicated elsewhere more than once) on that server. The information about the WD idle timer is relevant, as the other disks in this server are WD Green as well. Regarding normalization, presumably the manufacturer knows their product best, so that's still useful.

Answer (score 0):

> However, all Old_age attributes feature a THRESH of 0.

That's because there is no fixed threshold below which the drive is considered "failing". These values just decrease with age.

Values are normed to 100 for "normal operation", and lower is worse. Above 100 is "fine", below 100 indicates "substandard, but still working", below threshold indicates "this drive has definitely gone bad".

Your values look fine: Low raw read errors, no reallocated sectors, two sectors pending reallocation (which can happen, no need for alarm yet).

You have a high load cycle count, which is a bug in some WD Green drives. (Google to find out what to do about that, I had one of those. It can be fixed.).

> My real question is whether I should get rid of this disk.

The disk looks fine and will probably keep working for years. However, because of age and the high load cycle count, definitely make a backup (just in case).

Comment: Where do see age information in the original posting? The load cycle count is not high in absolute terms. It is high in relationship to the time the drive was spinning. The high load cycle count is not a bug. It is a result of a dubious effort to save power. Normalized values are more or less useless.

Comment: @r2d3 the bug is in the interaction with how linux uses the harddisk (WD driver unloads, Linux does delayed write from kernel elevator, WD drive loads, rinse and repeat). You already have mentioned the tool to fix it in your answer. It's the raw counts which are "useless", because there is no guarantee that the value means anything. Often they are what you think they are, sometimes they are not. The normed counts always work, that's why the standard has them...

Comment: Regarding the overarching question whether I should keep or dump that drive, both your and r2d3's answers are useful (although they say the opposite). At least I can keep it for data that has good backups.

Comment: @berndbausch and if you do that, you can also verify our predictions: see what state the drive is in one year or so, and come back and update this question. And do fix the head unload problem if you want to keep using it. I did that to my WD after it had racked up quite a few load cycles, and it kept working fine afterwards.